# Cancelling summands in a direct sum decomposition

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $M$ be a Noetherian and Artinian module. Suppose that:
$$\bigoplus_{i=1}^{q} A_{i} \oplus \bigoplus_{i=1}^{t} B_{i} \cong  \bigoplus_{i=1}^{q} A_{i} \oplus \bigoplus_{i=1}^{r} C_{i}$$

where all $A_{i},B_{i},C_{i}$ are indecomposable submodules of $M$.

Can we always guarantee that $B_{i} \cong C_{i}$ for all $i \in \{1,2,...,t\}$? That is, can we "cancel" the term $\displaystyle\bigoplus_{i=1}^{q} A_{i}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cancellation means that for modules   $M,N,P$ over a ring $R$ (not assumed commutative) we have the implication

$$M\oplus N\cong M\oplus P \implies N\cong P$$
Cancellation holds for modules that are only  assumed artinian  (which of course answers your question in the affirmative) thanks to a theorem by Camps and Dicks.

This is quite astonishing, since 
 Krull-Schmidt does *not* hold for modules that are just supposed artinian.
And, again  astonishingly, a counter-example was found only in [1995](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1995-123-12/S0002-9939-1995-1277109-4/S0002-9939-1995-1277109-4.pdf) .

Finally, let me point out that a very general Krull-Schmidt theorem was proved in a categorical setting by [Atiyah](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/BSMF/BSMF_1956__84_/BSMF_1956__84__307_0/BSMF_1956__84__307_0.pdf). The main application of his results is to coherent sheaves in  algebraic geometry .

Comment: Dear @user, the reference is: Camps and Dicks, Israel Journal of Mathematics Volume 81, Numbers 1-2, 203-211.  And, no,  "just taking quotients" won't work in general: check the concept "stably isomorphic but not isomorphic".

Comment: The flaw is that you may not quotient common summands  in isomorphisms: else you would have cancellation for all modules over all rings!

Comment: Dear user, the (admittedly subtle) point is that if $M=A_1\oplus A_2$ (i.e. $A_i\subset M $) , you may deduce that $M/A_1\cong A_2$ but you may not if you only have $M\cong A_1\oplus A_2$. Think it over! If you still have difficulties, ask a new question: this thread is already very long...